# Unable to save data in Firebase Realtime Database from Android app

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

progress dialog does not dismiss and because of no response from firebase real-time database
I add also authentication another page its works, but save information in realtime won't work, I create a firebase real-time bucket also

this is a simple test but no response progress is running.

```
btnLogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String txt_email=email.getText().toString();
            String txt_password=password.getText().toString();
            final ProgressDialog progressDialog =new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loging in");
            progressDialog.show();

            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");
            reference.push().setValue("hi").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void () {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "no success "+ task.getException().getMessage()
                                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "fail : "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

[this is my rules of realtime data base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yWFK.png)

[this is my real time data base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrN2m.png)

[This is actually my firebase integration works or not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ensGg.png)

and registration code is below. authentication works but real-time not works. don't store data and don't give me any type of message. and progress dialog is running not dismiss because of real-time not response.

```
 private void register(final String username, final String email, String password, final String phone){
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        FirebaseUser firebaseUser=auth.getCurrentUser();
                        assert firebaseUser!=null;
                        String userid = firebaseUser.getUid();

                        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);

                        HashMap<String ,String> hashMap= new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("id", userid);
                        hashMap.put("username", username);
                        hashMap.put("imageUrl","default");


                        hashMap.put("email",email);
                        hashMap.put("phone",phone);
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "sign in but not insert", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        reference.setValue(hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                   /* SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                                    editor.putString(STATUS,"student");
                                    editor.apply();*/
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "finish set up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Intent intent= new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }else {
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "failed to add database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

please help me how can I fix the real-time database?

Comment: Since your database is in a non-default region, you may have to specify the database URL in the code: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("database URL here")`.

Comment: Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: what is the database URL actually is it realtime databse bucket name? sir

Comment: I did the project of a firebase in 2019 then did not do any URL in the getInstance() method actually. but nowadays in 2021 what is changed, can you tell me about that